# Fill a column in sql table with the number of unique values of a column from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hiveql

I have two sql tables t1 and t2, I want to fill a column in t1 with the number of unique values in a column in t2.

Example: t1 has two column `a` and `count`

```
   a   count
1  1  
2  1  
3  2
```

Example: t2 has one column b

```
   b 
1  3  
2  3  
3  2
4  5
5  5
```

t2 has 3 unique values in column b, I want to have t1 like this, column `count` to be filled by the number of unique values in t2.b

```
   a  count
1  1  3
2  1  3
3  2  3
```

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL Server. Don't spam tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your tables

```
declare @t1 table(
   FIELD1 INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,a      INTEGER  NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO @t1(FIELD1,a) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO @t1(FIELD1,a) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO @t1(FIELD1,a) VALUES (3,2);

declare @t2 table(
  b      INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @t2(b) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO @t2(b) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO @t2(b) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO @t2(b) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO @t2(b) VALUES (5);
```

your select

```
select FIELD1,a

,(select count(distinct b) from @t2) as count1 

from @t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get your question wrong.
I guess you want to find out all distinct values in t2 and their counts.
What you need is `GROUP BY` and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
   a INTEGER,
   count INTEGER
);


CREATE TABLE t2
(
   b INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(3);

INSERT INTO t1
    (a, count)
SELECT
    b,
    count(b)
FROM
    t2
GROUP by
    b;
    
SELECT * FROM t1;
```